# Is there any status of review comments in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

we are going to use gerrit for the source code reviewing and code repository. as we know, for each change, anyone can review it, and give the comments in specific line of source code.

My question is, is there any state of the review comments such like (new/open/closed)? or how to check previous review findings have been fixed or still open there?

Is there any life cycle of review comment? and how to measure it?  I used gerrit REST API to read it, but no such information there, or I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. It would be useful as a new patchset will hide previous comments and it is not clear which comments have been fixed and closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.  Comments don't have a state or any kind of tracking between patch sets.

Basically you have to rely on the change owner adding a "Done" comment at the same line (on the same patch set).

Also note that if there are multiple comments on the same line, it's not possible to reply to a specific one.